# Flutter || google_maps_flutter package || marker issue

Tags: flutter, google-maps, bloc

Google map is introduce which set. when i click on the marker it shows infoWindow. if i click on infoWindow, i want the page to navigate to another page.

1. At the google map, only last marker is shown.
2. if i solved the no1 problem, then cliking on other marker, it always keep clicking on the last marker.

```
  BlocBuilder<LiveMembersCubit, LiveMembersState> _buildMap(
    LiveMembersCubit bloc,
    LocationService locationService,
  ) {
    Position? location = locationService.userLocation;

    return BlocBuilder<LiveMembersCubit, LiveMembersState>(
      buildWhen: (previous, current) {
        if (previous.status != current.status ||
            previous.data.length != current.data.length) {
          for (int i = 0; i < current.data.length; i++) {
            var marker = Marker(
              markerId: MarkerId(current.data[i].id.toString()),
              position: LatLng(
                current.data[i].location.coordinates[1],
                current.data[i].location.coordinates[0],
              ),
              icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
                BitmapDescriptor.hueGreen,
              ),
              infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                title: current.data[i].name,
                snippet: current.data[i].club?.name,
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (_) => OthersProfilePage(
                        userId: current.data[i].userId,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );

            _markers.add(marker);
          }

          //ignore: no-empty-block
          setState(() {});

          return true;
        }

        return false;
      },



                  GoogleMap(
                    onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                      _mapController = controller;
                    },
                    rotateGesturesEnabled: false,
                    tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
                    // zoomGesturesEnabled: false,
                    zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                    myLocationEnabled: true,
                    myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                    gestureRecognizers: {
                      Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
                        () => EagerGestureRecognizer(),
                      )
                    },
                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target: LatLng(
                        location!.latitude,
                        location.longitude,
                      ),
                      zoom: initialZoomLevel,
                    ),
                    circles: {
                      Circle(
                        circleId: const CircleId('1'),
                        center: LatLng(
                          location.latitude,
                          location.longitude,
                        ),
                        radius: _radius * 1609.34,
                        strokeWidth: 1,
                        strokeColor: AppColors.transparent,
                        fillColor: AppColors.transparent,
                      ),
                    },
                    markers: _markers.toSet(),
                  ),
```

1. Tried to generate set of marker from the bloc at the marker, it shows the marker but cliking on the infoWindow, it directed to the last element.

Comment: Can you please clarify what the issue really is? And the community would really appreciate it if you can provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the steps that demonstrates the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: I've solved the issue by providing a unique id to the makerId parameter.

It was set to the same value, so marker could not identify uniquely and clicking on the marker - it was redirect to the profile indicating by the last element.